# Bootstrap Grid System: Bad wrapping of horizontal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was just building up a form using bootstrap and the `.form-horizontal` tag, having 4 columns in a row like

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row span12">
      <div class="control-group span3">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span3">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group span3">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>                    
      <div class="control-group span3">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but when resizing it, it really lays out badly as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/juristr/XXXqN/
*(Just try resizing the HTML window to see the effect)*

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?? Isn't Bootstrap capable of automatically wrapping down the items that do not fit any more, ending in having 2 columns per row??

Comment: Try removing the span12 class from the row around the form. Also your form tag should be moved up one </div> I think.

Comment: @BillyMoat Did already try that before...doesn't change. There's still this odd overlapping at a certain size of the browser where instead (imho) it should wrap to the next line.

Comment: @BillyMoat I didn't understand how I should move the form tag up??

Comment: In your jsfiddle the end form tag should be moved inside the end div tag which is above it.

Comment: the form contains the whole row div...the other one is from the container which finishes below the footer...the formatting is a bit bad in the fiddle, just copied it over from my IDE

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can use form controls for the form to fit cause it has its own margins. Check it this works

```
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="span3">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="span12" placeholder="Password"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/causesevenatenine/CBS5y/)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it doesn't work at all, or at least not in the expected way. What I want to achieve is to have 4 columns in a row and to have it wrapped in case some columns don't fit due to resizing of the browser or different screen sizes. In your example each of the field finishes in a separate row which is not want I want.

Comment: I misunderstood question .. please check whether the edit helps.

Comment: Doesn't cause any change to my code...actually, where is the difference to my version (other than `row-fluid`)?

Comment: Yep, was just playing around with something similar. the `span` on the input fields was missing...but the problem is that now it's no more horizontal actually.